# Position relative and z-index confusion

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCBXA/)

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around z-index with relatively positioned elements. Given this html I want the 'active' screen-component to be in front of the other two (yes I know this visually doesn't look good in this example... I've boiled down the problem to the basics):

```
<div class="parent-container">
    <div class="screen-component">
        Content inside first screen component
    </div>
    <div class="screen-component">
        Content inside second screen component
    </div>
    <div class="screen-component active">
        Content inside active component.. I want this up top
    </div>    
</div>
```

And this css:

```
.parent-container {
    position: relative;
}

.screen-component {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.screen-component.active {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5000;
}
```

The desired effect I want is any 'screen-component' with the 'active' class to be positioned in front of the other ones; however right now they all seem to be given new lines, despite the .active class having a z-index higher than the .screen-component class

Comment: I believe `z-index` doesn't work in jsFiddle. Just incase you was only trying to on there

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working in my development environment either

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding z-index... it's for depth, for putting stuff behind and in front of other stuff, not above or below.

Comment: The desired effect I want is for the 'active' screen-component to be in front of the other two... edited main question to better reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZCBXA/3/

(The background colors are just for demonstration purposes)

```
.parent-container {
    position: relative;
}

.screen-component {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.active {
    z-index: 5000;
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than force a particular background color, just give .screen-component a z-index of -1 and .active a z-index of 0.

Comment: Good suggestion, the background color is just for demonstration purposes. Updated the answer with that note.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, you need `position: absolute;` not `position: relative;`.  Then give the div class a top value so that all divs with that class are the same distance from the top, and a z-index of -1 to hide them.  The only thing the active class needs is a higher z-index than the others.

```
.parent-container {
    position: relative;
}

.screen-component {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.screen-component.active {
    z-index: 0;
}
```